# Broken Unity project after git clone

Tags: git, unity-game-engine, version-control, git-lfs

I have a Unity project ([github link](https://github.com/raidenfreeman/ExperimentNew)), that doesn't work after being cloned. Even though the files are there, they have incorrect contents. For example .png files are replaced with text:

> version https://git-lfs.github.com/spec/v1
> oid sha256:089f8198df161233681006c4243f6d6babb2e125062a21ea727d0d6c97889d26
> size 1035

Some DLLs that I have from external asset packages (for example DOTween), are also probably not stored correctly, because the compiler complains about undeclared namespaces.

> Assets/External Dependencies/Demigiant/DOTween/Examples/Basics.cs(3,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `DG' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?

**UPDATE:**
Actually, the dlls are not even there. Why? They're not part of the gitignore.

I have made sure to set `Version Control Mode` to `Visible Meta Files` and
`Asset Serialization Mode` to `Force Text`.

I tried moving the project to a new directory, deleting the .git folder, deleting `Library`, remaking everything (reopening with Unity, and then `git init`), and pushing to a new repo. The new repo has the exact same issues as the previous one.

I'm using the [default .gitignore for Unity](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Unity.gitignore)

And the following .gitattributes (to enable LFS):

```
# 3D models
*.3dm filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.3ds filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.blend filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.c4d filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.collada filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.dae filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.dxf filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.fbx filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.jas filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.lws filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.lxo filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.ma filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.max filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.mb filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.obj filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.ply filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.skp filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.stl filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.ztl filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
# Audio
*.aif filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.aiff filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.it filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.mod filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.mp3 filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.ogg filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.s3m filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.wav filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.xm filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
# Fonts
*.otf filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.ttf filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
# Images
*.bmp filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.exr filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.gif filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.hdr filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.iff filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.jpeg filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.jpg filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.pict filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.png filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.psd filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.tga filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.tif filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.tiff filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
# Collapse Unity-generated files on GitHub
*.asset linguist-generated
*.mat linguist-generated
*.meta linguist-generated
*.prefab linguist-generated
*.unity linguist-generated
```

---

## UPDATE:

After further investigation, it seems that the png files, get overwritten (by unity?) when the project gets opened after cloning. They exist correctly in the remote repository. The external dlls on the other hand do not get uploaded at all.

Comment: For me it's a problem with git-lfs. Is it installed on your computer?

Comment: Yes it's installed. I'm also pretty certain it's with git-lfs. I'll reinstall it.

Comment: @K.Gkinis Has your problem been solved yet?

Comment: @MarinaLiu-MSFT No, but I haven't had the time to try anything new.

Comment: @K.Gkinis Ok, you can have a try and feedback the result when you are free.

Answer (score 2):

Your `.gitattributes` file is wrong.

> `*.png filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text`

Text? TEXT? Why on earth would you want to treat .png files as text? Same goes for most of those other attributes.

Looking at my *own* `.gitattributes` file, I have this:
(Yes, most of the lines are comments)

```
###############################################################################
# Set default behavior to automatically normalize line endings.
###############################################################################
* text=auto
###############################################################################
# Set default behavior for command prompt diff.
#
# This is need for earlier builds of msysgit that does not have it on by
# default for csharp files.
# Note: This is only used by command line
###############################################################################
#*.cs     diff=csharp

###############################################################################
# Set the merge driver for project and solution files
#
# Merging from the command prompt will add diff markers to the files if there
# are conflicts (Merging from VS is not affected by the settings below, in VS
# the diff markers are never inserted). Diff markers may cause the following 
# file extensions to fail to load in VS. An alternative would be to treat
# these files as binary and thus will always conflict and require user
# intervention with every merge. To do so, just uncomment the entries below
###############################################################################
#*.sln       merge=binary
#*.csproj    merge=binary
#*.vbproj    merge=binary
#*.vcxproj   merge=binary
#*.vcproj    merge=binary
#*.dbproj    merge=binary
#*.fsproj    merge=binary
#*.lsproj    merge=binary
#*.wixproj   merge=binary
#*.modelproj merge=binary
#*.sqlproj   merge=binary
#*.wwaproj   merge=binary

###############################################################################
# behavior for image files
#
# image files are treated as binary by default.
###############################################################################
#*.jpg   binary
#*.png   binary
#*.gif   binary

###############################################################################
# diff behavior for common document formats
# 
# Convert binary document formats to text before diffing them. This feature
# is only available from the command line. Turn it on by uncommenting the 
# entries below.
###############################################################################
#*.doc   diff=astextplain
#*.DOC   diff=astextplain
#*.docx  diff=astextplain
#*.DOCX  diff=astextplain
#*.dot   diff=astextplain
#*.DOT   diff=astextplain
#*.pdf   diff=astextplain
#*.PDF   diff=astextplain
#*.rtf   diff=astextplain
#*.RTF   diff=astextplain
```

This file was created automatically for me when I created the git repository through the GitHub desktop application. I've heard that it's "not very good" but I've found that it does what I need it to. Namely not get in the way of making commits and pushing to GitHub.

Comment: the -text attribute is for removing text property and treat this file as binary file. So I think your answer is misleading.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this section for git clone to fetch your lfs files.

```
# Collapse Unity-generated files on GitHub
*.asset linguist-generated
*.mat linguist-generated
*.meta linguist-generated
*.prefab linguist-generated
*.unity linguist-generated
```

`git clone` reads the `.gitattribute` file before deciding whether to resolve lfs files. If it finds syntax it can't understand it aborts the process. I thik `linguist-generated` is a non-standard attribute that's causing your repo to not pull in the changes.

I don't have the reputation to comment on the other answer, but `-text` is not the problem.

In gitattribute files adding a `-` before a property "unsets" the property. In this case it means do not treat it as text.

From https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes:

> "Unsetting the text attribute on a path tells Git not to attempt any
>   end-of-line conversion upon checkin or checkout."

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use LFS to track DLL files, it will cause your DLL compile error.

I also encounter this problem. Error: namespace doesn't exist. It turns out that a DLL containing that namespace was not downloaded. DLL contained symbolic link text instead. C# ignored that DLL and did load symbols -> compilation failed.

You can use the following commands to bring back the DLL files to normal:

```
git lfs untrack *.dll
git rm --cached *.dll
git add *.dll
git commit -m "add dll back to non-LFS files"
```

And then you do a fresh checkout could fix your problem.

Some part of my error messages are:

> the class com.tencent.pandora.WsOPCancelSubscribe could not be loaded,
> used in Assembly-CSharp, Version=2.0.0.668, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=null The class
> com.tencent.pandora.WsOPCancelSubscribeAck could not be loaded, used
> in Assembly-CSharp, Version=2.0.0.668, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=null The class com.tencent.pandora.WsSendMsgAck could
> not be loaded, used in Assembly-CSharp, Version=2.0.0.668,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null The class
> com.tencent.pandora.WsBarrageItem could not be loaded, used in
> Assembly-CSharp, Version=2.0.0.668, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=null The class com.tencent.pandora.BulletWebSocket
> could not be loaded, used in Assembly-CSharp, Version=2.0.0.668,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null The class
> c__Iterator0 could not be loaded, used in
> Assembly-CSharp, Version=2.0.0.668, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=null The class com.tencent.pandora.WsEventData could
> not be loaded, used in Assembly-CSharp, Version=2.0.0.668,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null The class
> com.tencent.pandora.WsEventScene could not be loaded, used in
> Assembly-CSharp, Version=2.0.0.668, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=null The class com.tencent.pandora.WsEventItem could
> not be loaded, used in Assembly-CSharp, Version=2.0.0.668,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null The class
> com.tencent.pandora.WsTerminalPage could not be loaded, used in
> Assembly-CSharp, Version=2.0.0.668, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=null The class com.tencent.pandora.WsOPSubscribe could
> not be loaded, used in Assembly-CSharp, Version=2.0.0.668,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null The class
> com.tencent.pandora.WsOPHeartBeat could not be loaded, used in
> Assembly-CSharp, Version=2.0.0.668, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=null The class com.tencent.pandora.WsOPHeartbeatAck
> could not be loaded, used in Assembly-CSharp, Version=2.0.0.668,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null The class
> com.tencent.pandora.WsOPCancelSubscribe could not be loaded, used in
> Assembly-CSharp, Version=2.0.0.668, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=null The class
> com.tencent.pandora.WsOPCancelSubscribeAck could not be loaded, used
> in Assembly-CSharp, Version=2.0.0.668, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=null The class com.tencent.pandora.WsSendMsgAck could
> not be loaded, used in Assembly-CSharp, Version=2.0.0.668,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null The class
> com.tencent.pandora.WsBarrageItem could not be loaded, used in
> Assembly-CSharp, Version=2.0.0.668, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=null The class com.tencent.pandora.BulletWebSocket
> could not be loaded, used in Assembly-CSharp, Version=2.0.0.668,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null The class
> c__Iterator0 could not be loaded, used in
> Assembly-CSharp, Version=2.0.0.668, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=null The class com.tencent.pandora.WsEventData could
> not be loaded, used in Assembly-CSharp, Version=2.0.0.668,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null The class
> com.tencent.pandora.WsEventScene could not be loaded, used in
> Assembly-CSharp, Version=2.0.0.668, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=null

If anyone encounters the same problem as me, you could just check your ProjectSettings.asset file, you shouldn't set LF line endings to it, leave it as LFCR and my problem magically disappeared.